# What maximal integer, capable of adding 1 a float type can hold in c++?

Tags: c++, types, floating-point, terminology, numeric-limits

Suppose I am using `float` to hold integer values and adding small shifts to it, approximately 1s or 2s. At which value `float` will stop to change? What is the name of this value?

Comment: "*At which value `float` will stop to change?*" - what do you mean? Any arithmetic operation you do on a `float` is going to change its value, regardless of its result, whether it overflows, etc. There is no "stop" value that prevents further changes from happening.

Comment: your title says 'integer'.  Your question says 'float', as does the tag you added....

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't understand. If float is very big say 1e100, then adding 1 won't change it, am I wrong?

Comment: Why are you using a float to hold integer values?  Use an integer!

Comment: @Dims that example produces ["infinity"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/INFINITY)

Comment: Perhaps you want to rephrase this questions to clarify that you want to know the smallest float `x` such that `x == x+1` and `x` represents a positive integer.

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for this but the is a function [std::nextafter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) that gives you the next possible value for a given floating-point number.

Comment: @Dims -- you're absolutely right that when you add a very small value to a large floating-point value the result can be the original large floating-point value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest positive value of an IEEE 754 floating-point variable `a` where you get `a == a+1` is `2^bits_precision`, where `bits_precision` is one more than the number of bits in the significand and can be found with `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`.

For a 32-bit `float`, that's 24; for a 64-bit `double`, that's 53 (again, in the very common context of IEEE 754).

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38e6aefa43e8fab2)

Comment: A minor point: those values are for 32-bit **IEEE-754** `float` and for 64-bit **IEEE-754** `double`. Compilers aren't required to use those types, so it's possible that some obscure system uses a different representation for floating-point types, with different sizes and/or different tradeoffs between the size of the significand and the size of the exponent. +1.